# Windows batch, How to rename a directory to date and time with seconds

Tags: windows, command-line, batch, rename

Windows batch,
How to rename a directory to date and time with seconds

Current drive and directory is S:\1 = a backup.

via batch, How to automate, How to rename a directory, not a file?
something like -- Rename S:\1 S:\20171022_131459

2017 year
10 October
22 day
13 hours
14 minutes
59 seconds

Below was does at the command line with one %
on a file named **hope.txt**, not a directory

```
ren hope.txt 20171022.txt
```

.

```
for /f "tokens=1-4 delims=- " %d in ("%date%") do rename "hope.txt" %d%e%f.txt
```

and in part 2 (time)
Seconds are missing in name and
it is not a directory, but, it does a file
named **hope.txt** with hours and minutes.

```
rename "hope.txt" 1314.txt
```

.

```
for /f "tokens=1-2 delims=: " %G in ("%time%") do rename "hope.txt" %G%H.txt
```

--

Comment: Depending on your Windows version, you may not be able to rename a directory with `ren`: you may need to use `move` instead.

Comment: On Windows 10/11 you can simply rename a directory: `ren old new`. Otherwise use `move old new`. If you need to know how to format date and time I'd suggest to do it as described in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23558738/1879699).

Answer (score 0):

Below is one answer to renaming a directory
From C:\99
To _ C:\YearMMDD_hhMMssFF
(Year Month Day _ hours Minutes seconds Fraction of 1 second)

C:\99  might be the name of a file
C:\99  might be the name of a directory

On Windows XP 32 bit, ren works.
(ren = rename Directory or File)

On this one computer we have **3 delimiters of - : .**

Date time format of:
Date ______ time
2017-10-23 19:28:13.01
a___ b__c__d__e__f__g

Answer, cmd line:

```
for /f "tokens=1-7 delims=-:. " %a in ("%date% %time%") do ren c:\99 %a%b%c_%d%e%f%g
```

Directory C:\99
Directory **C:\20171023_19473074**

.

Answer, batch file with double %%:

```
for /f "tokens=1-7 delims=-:. " %%a in ("%date% %time%") do ren c:\99 %%a%%b%%c_%%d%%e%%f%%g
```

Directory C:\99
Directory **C:\20171023_19480420**

--

Comment: why do you use XP in 2017?

Answer (score -1):

I think this does what you are looking for:

```
for /f "tokens=2-7 delims=/:. " %a in ("%date% %time%") do ren dir1 %c%ab%b_%d%e%f
```

The output looks like this:

```
ren dir1 201710b22_201108
```

In a batch file you need extra % so this line becomes:

```
for /f "tokens=2-7 delims=/:. " %%a in ("%date% %time%") do ren dir1 %%c%%ab%%b_%%d%%e%%f
```

Comment: `%date%`  and `%time%` are both [locale dependent](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56165593/995714), so using them is a very bad idea

Comment: Thats All well and good except my code allowed for that.

Comment: who said that the OPs and readers of this also use the same locale as you?